# Excel: Summing multiple amount that are multiply at different time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find a formula that could help me with the sum I'm trying to do.

I have a file with differents amounts received at different period that need to be accrued on 13 period and next to that I have a column with a year to that of what is collected.

Exemple in P1 I received 15 000$ which is 1 154$ monthly. Next period I have a additional amount of 200 000$ divided by 13 amount to 15 385$ for a new YTD P2 at 17 693.

The formula I used looks like this for Period 2:

```
=E3*B4+D4
```

Period 3 looks like this:

```
=$E$3*$B5+$D$4*(B5-$B$4)+D5
```

Period 4 looks like this:

```
=$E$3*$B6+$D$4*(B6-$B$4+1)+$D$5*(B6-$B$5+1)+D6
```

And I added to the formula like this until my P13. Is there any other way this could be done ? You can find below an example of the formulas on multiple line:

[Link to example file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/6um5cgwnvj37n6j/example_stack_overflow.xlsx/file)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your math is a little off (even though your year end totals are correct).
This is my suggestion:
Add in a column between Monthly and YTD for Monthly Collections. The formula in that column will be `=D3` in the first used cell, and then drag down `=E3+D4` and so on til the end of the list.
Then in the YTD column put `=E3` in the first used cell, and then drag down `=F3+E4` and so on til the end of the list.

This should help you eliminate the long manual formulas.

Comment: This was much simpler then I think it would be thank you! I think I was focusing too much in finding a formula that would be the same in every cell with no addition.